# How do I set up a kind of "belongs_to :through" association without a direct belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that "belongs_to :through" is not valid. It's just my attempt to express what I want to achieve. Just bear with me for a sec...

This is what I have:

```
class League
  has_many :divisions
end

class Division
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :players
end

class Player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Now, in order to make a "baseball card" view form, I need:

```
name
team.name
team.division.name
team.division.league.name
```

So, is there a way to set up a "belongs_to :through" association to directly access 'division.name' from 'players_controller' without the 'team.' prefix?? I have to access a lot of columns from 'player' to 'division', so I'm looking for a way to get "direct" access to those columns.

One option is to include a 'division_id' column in the 'players' table, but I've been told that it would kinda break the relational data model, since it would allow for inconsistency if the data selection functionality is not properly handled (e.g. player A is on team A which is in division A, but player A has its division_id column set to division B).

Is it possible to make a "symbolic link", e.g. 'division' now refers to 'team.division', and 'league' now refers to 'team.division.league'??

Or, is the only true option to use the full path each time??

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use delegate in the model class.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :players

  delegate :league, to: :division
end
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Comment: This is the best approach, and should be selected instead of blackbird07's.

Comment: I aggree! <text to satisfy comment length restriction>

Comment: This is elegant but you need to do one query for each level in objects tree. So if you need only top object it's possible to pack it in one SQL query. There will be subsequent queries ofc, but still only one transfer `rails -(query)-> database -(result)-> rails`. Unfortunately I don't know hot to do it with rails query interface. Anyone knows?

Comment: Third answer answers my question... :)

Comment: easy, I would also delegate the id like so `delegate :league, :league_id, to: :division`

Answer (score 8):

You may try

```
    class Player
      belongs_to :team
      has_one :division, :through => :team
    end
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do this. A has_one relation suggests a belongs_to relation in the other model through a foreign key. But `Division` doesn't `belongs_to :team`, it `has_many :teams`, which means the Team `belongs_to :division`. Matt Smith got it right: you can also use this logic in the Player class: `delegate :division, :to => :team`.

Comment: I agree with you - for the current state of Rails. But I'm wondering why there is no belongs_to :through.

Comment: O.o! This works with minimum number of queries. I think there should be `belongs_to :through`! Moreover your solution caches the result of `division` query.

Comment: @JaapHaagmans `has_one :through` is actually correct here, as far as I can tell.`has_one` is simply the Rails term for a 1:1 association where this model doesn't have the foreign key field—the exact case here. The fact that `Division belongs_to :team` is not relevant in this respect.

Comment: But @MarnenLaibow-Koser, because on the other side of the `has_one` relationship, you would expect a `belongs_to` statement, while Division would `has_many :players, :through => :teams`. The ActiveRecord API also says this about `has_many`: `This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key.`

Comment: @JaapHaagmans Right! The "other" table (not class) contains the foreign key in this case—but when `:through` is involved, the "other" class is the `:through` table (i.e. the proximate association), not the ultimate destination. `belongs_to :division` would actually be semantically incorrect, because it would imply that a field `players.division_id` existed—which it doesn't.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: But that's exactly why I liked the `delegate` solution so much! It's immediately apparent what's happening when looking at the Player and Team classes. But okay, I'll take back that "you shouldn't do this" as I see what you mean: my bias is not defendable :)

Comment: @JaapHaagmans `delegate` works pretty well if all you want is a definition of `Player#division`. But if you use `has_one :through`, you get all the other Rails association methods, which are sometimes what's needed.

Comment: From the docs for the `:through` option for `has_one`:
"Specifies a Join Model through which to perform the query. Options for :class_name, :primary_key, and :foreign_key are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection. You can only use a :through query through a has_one or belongs_to association on the join model."
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Answer (score 7):

You can define a helper method in your player model:

```
def division
  team.division
end

def league
  team.division.league
end
```

Of course, this only relates to readability of your code and does not affect the form of the database queries involved. If your statement generates multiple SQL queries but you want only one, check out the `.include` option here: [Rails Guides - Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)