# Why does Rails not have a belongs_to through method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

As outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834073/how-to-setup-a-kind-of-belongs-to-through-without-setting-up-a-direct-belongs), a `belongs_to :x, through: :y` relation is best achieved with the delegate method.

Is there a particular reason (technical reason, design choice) as to why Rails does not support belongs_to through relations?

```
class Division
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :players
end

class Player
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :division, through: :team # WON'T WORK
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would work like this instead of using through.

```
belongs_to :division, class_name: Team
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to why, but there's a consistent top-down pattern in ActiveRecord methods. The functionality you're looking for is already provided by `has_many :through`—it's just a matter of placing the statement in the ancestor rather than the descendent object:

> The has_many :through association is also useful for setting up
>   "shortcuts" through nested has_many associations. For example, if a document has many sections, and a section has many paragraphs, you may sometimes want to get a simple collection of all paragraphs in the document. [[source: Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)]

In your case, that would look like the following:

```
class Division
  belongs_to :league
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, through: :teams
end

class Team
  belongs_to :division
  has_many :players
end

class Player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

You can then call `league.players` to get an array of players in the given league or `player.league` to get a given player's league.