# How to use includes method with 2 belongs_to associations?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm currently using Rails 4.

I have 3 classes, like this

```
class FirstLevel < AR::Base
  has_many :second_levels
  has_many :third_levels, :through => :second_levels
end

class SecondLevel < AR::Base
  has_many :third_levels
  belongs_to :first_level
end

class ThirdLevel < AR::Base
  belongs_to :second_level
end
```

If I want to get a set of `first_levels` and automatically load `third_levels` I can use

```
FirstLevel.includes(:third_levels).where(...)
```

The problem is that I want a set of `third_levels` and automatically load `first_levels`... The command

```
ThirdLevel.includes(:first_level).where(...)
```

doesn't work, because `first_level` is not declared as an association.

There is several possibilities :

- Declare `delegate :first_level, :to => :second_level` in the `ThirdLevel` class... But it's not either an association.
- Declare `has_one :first_level, :through => :second_level`, but it's not respecting the structure of my tables.

Is there any possibility to declare the association between a `third_level` and a `first_level` ? The method `ThirdLevel.joins({ :second_level => :first_level })` returns the `id` of the `first_levels`, why Rails coulnd not load this `first_levels`...

Comment: @emaillenin written too fast. `has_many` of course.

Comment: What is the problem with `has_one :through`?

Comment: @BroiSatse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834073/how-to-setup-a-kind-of-belongs-to-through-without-setting-up-a-direct-belongs (Last answer)