# Implementing has_many :through to Subcategories in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I would like to implement subcategories for my Products.

So far I have this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, dependent: :destroy
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

And it works totally OK, however I would like to take this further and implement a has_many through association between these models, so that every Product will belong to a Category through a subcategory (so that I could check how many products are in a certain category in total, etc.). But cant seem to get it right. Does this even make sense or should I just stick with the first version I have on top?

Comment: It looks to me like for Subcategory that should be `belongs_to :category` rather than `has_one :category`. Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834073/how-to-setup-a-kind-of-belongs-to-through-without-setting-up-a-direct-belongs for how to do the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For checking how many products are in a certain category, how about adding:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :subcategories
end
```

For the inverse (that is, going from products to categories), it is my understanding that Rails does not have a `belongs_to :through` association type.  What you could do instead is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def category
    subcategory.category
  end
end
```

Another, shorthand way to write this would be using `delegate`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :category, to: :subcategory, prefix: false
end
```

Comment: And what kind of relations do I have to specify within the Subcategory model?

Comment: You could leave unchanged from your example, or as @Coenwulf suggested, change `has_one :category` to `belongs_to  :category`