# Rails 4 HABTM has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Team, looking for some help for a very specific (newbie) situation on a Rails 4 association.
We have 3 models:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :lines, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products, through: :lines, dependent: :destroy
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :brand
 has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :lines
 has_many :brands, through: :lines
end
```

This configuration works well when trying to check for `Products` under specific `Brand` (or `Line`) and viceversa: different `Brands` (or `Lines`) available for a specific `Product`. However, when it comes to delete/destroy there is an issue. We are getting this Rspec error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughCantAssociateThroughHasOneOrManyReflection:
Cannot modify association 'Brand#products' because the source reflection 
class 'Product' is associated to 'Line' via :has_and_belongs_to_many.
```

We have made research on this exception, checked for Rails API, with no luck, examples found are showing a different model configuration. What's missing on this approach?

Appreciate your help guys!

Comment: how are you trying to access?

Comment: add a little bit more of controller code.

Comment: I've not seen a habtm on a through table before. This intervening model is usually used to track meta data around the association between the two other models. So I would suggest brand_product as a through table and keep line separate.

Comment: @sahil product.brands (brands eligible by this product) / brand.products (products under this brand) im trying to remove associations from a specific brand (and its lines) once it gets deleted. I like this approach but how we can mix Line with Products? Keep in mind that, 1 Brand has many Lines, and then, Line has and belongs to many Products... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be something like this:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :lines, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :products, through: :lines, dependent: :destroy
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :brand
 has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :brand, through: :line
 has_and_belongs_to_many :lines
end
```

And in migrations:

```
create_table :brands , force: true do |t|
  t.string :name
  ...
  t.timestamps null: false    
end

create_table :lines , force: true do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.belongs_to :brand
  ...
  t.timestamps null: false    
end

create_table :products , force: true do |t|
  t.string :name
  ...
  t.timestamps null: false    
end

create_table :line_products, force: true, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :line, index: true
  t.belongs_to :product, index: true
end
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: hey, thanks for your help.. i also checked for this option but looks like is not valid... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834073/how-to-setup-a-kind-of-belongs-to-through-without-setting-up-a-direct-belongs

Comment: ok. Therefore some questions. How many brands have certain product? Fn How do You use it? `@brand.products << @product` is ussably when it have `includes` or `joins` before it.