# Rails scope with nested association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, scopes

I'm trying to get to grips with rails scopes.  I have the simple basics down but I'm trying to create a slightly more complex scope and I'm having some trouble.

```
class Client
  has_many :referrals, through: :submissions
  has_one :address
  has_many :submissions
end

class Submission
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :referrals, :inverse_of => :submission, dependent: :delete_all
end

class Referral
    belongs_to :branch
    belongs_to :submission
    has_one :client, through: :submission
end

class Address
    belongs_to :client
end
```

I also have users created using devise.  I have a custom attribute added to users called `city_town`.

When a user signs up, they select what city or town they are from and the agency that they work for.  When submissions are created, they take nested attributes for client details and address, as well as referral details. referrals take an agency_id that specifies where that referral is going to.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a scope that will collect all referrals where the `referral.client.address.city_town` matches the current user's city or town i.e: `current_user.city_town` and the agency_id of the referral matched the agency_id of the signed in user.

In short, when a user signs in, they can see referrals only for their agency and area.

So far I've got:

```
class Referral
  scope :agency_referrals, -> (id, city_town) { includes(:clients).where(agency_id: id, client.address.city_town => city_town) }
end
```

but I'm painfully aware that this is far from correct. I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `client' for #<Class:0x00000003200c08>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In which model you have that scope?

Comment: In the Referral class. I've edited my question to show that.

Comment: Try `includes(:client)` instead of `includes(:clients)`

Comment: I still get a similar error with client instead of clients.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175084/activerecord-query-through-multiple-joins

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ilya but I'm looking to achieve this using scopes.

Comment: Craig, I wonder if using the delegate might serve (. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14893450/1461972 ) . Maybe you can have   `delegate :client, to: :submission` , instead of `has_one :client, through: :submission` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving this particular error because you are improperly referencing the city_town in your query. `client.address.city_town => city_town` would imply that the key in this hash is a value nested within an existing "client" variable. This is more correct, and will likely remove the particular error you've just encountered:

By the way, the commenter Pavan was correct, `:client` should be singular in your `.includes()` statement. That said, I also expanded it to include the Address table up front, which may have caused additional errors.

```
# The .includes() parameters have been changed, and quotes have been added to the query.
scope :agency_referrals, -> (id, city_town) { includes(client: :address).where(agency_id: id, 'client.address.city_town' => city_town) }
```

Also, if you're looking for a non-string method of referencing the proper location (because this is Ruby, and we love our symbols), you could write this:

```
includes(:clients).where(agency_id: id, client: { address: { city_town: city_town } } => city_town)
```

I personally find this to be less clean, but it is a more "modern" format.

For further reference, you may wish to review [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will try this and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

could you try

```
includes(submission: :clients)
```

Comment: The asker would then have to change his reference to "submission.client.address.city_town", and be introducing an entirely unnecessary table to the mix.